# Having issues passing a password binding to a powershell script in jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am trying to password a password binding from jenkins to a powershell command line it works for passwords without special characters. But when i  introduce a password with special character it fails.

I tried using single and double quotes. It seems i am missing the escape sequence. I read it should be a ` but i am unsure how to introduce that using the jenkins $env:USER_PASSWORD

```
"--username=$ENV:DEV_USERNAME --password="$ENV:DEV_PASSWORD" --enviroment="dev""
```

I expect it to be able to pass a password with special characters with no failures.

Example:

if a password is "1234o!" I need to be able to pass that down using the powershell plugin

Comment: I noticed the issue to be related to some special characters that are bind to the DEV_PASSWORD variable. Is there a way for me to ignore the special characters or somehow pass the variable in quotes. Jenkins is not handling the special characters properly

Comment: I don't think you need 3 pairs of quotes, just one should do (or at worst have the same problem). Does this work: `"--username=$ENV:DEV_USERNAME --password=$ENV:DEV_PASSWORD --enviroment=dev"`?

Comment: I tried that combination and it failed. However the triple quotes around the password environment seemed to do the trick